# Awk - how to improve the regular expression?

Tags: awk

I have a file:

```
@Book{gjn2011ske, 
  author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
  title =    {Semantic Knowledge Engineering. A Rule-Based Approach},
  publisher =    {Wydawnictwa AGH},
  year =     2011,
  address =  {Krak\'ow}
}

@article{gjn2010jucs,
  Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
  Journal =  {Journal of Universal Computer Science},
  Number =   7,
  Pages =    {1006-1023},
  Title =    {Collective Knowledge Engineering with Semantic Wikis},
  Volume =   16,
  Year =     2010
}
```

I want to improve the regular expression that only removed the first line. **Note:** The record separator `RS="}\n"` can not be changed.

I tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="}\n" } {gsub(/@.*,/,"") ; print }' file
```

I want to print the result:

```
  author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
  title =    {Semantic Knowledge Engineering. A Rule-Based Approach},
  publisher =    {Wydawnictwa AGH},
  year =     2011,
  address =  {Krak\'ow}

  Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
  Journal =  {Journal of Universal Computer Science},
  Number =   7,
  Pages =    {1006-1023},
  Title =    {Collective Knowledge Engineering with Semantic Wikis},
  Volume =   16,
  Year =     2010
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

My proposed solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="}\n" }{sub(",","@"); sub(/@.*@/,""); print }' file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to accomplish what you want with the specified `RS` setting (because the `address =  {Krak\'ow}` has an extra record ending). I'd rather go with:

```
awk '$0 !~ "^@" && $0 !~ "^} *$" { print }' FILE
```

See it [in action here](http://ideone.com/rfOQN).

*EDIT* I don't know why it must be with a regexp solution, could you please explain it?

Anyway, yet another ([working, see here](http://ideone.com/dVEpq)) solution which uses regexp(s), but not the ones you are expecting.:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="}\n" }
{
  split($0,a,"\n")
  for (e=1;e<=length(a);e++) {
      if (a[e] ~ "{" && a[e] !~ "}") {
          sub("$","}",a[e])
      }
      if (a[e] ~ "=") { print a[e] }
  }
  printf("\n")
}' INPUTFILE
```

One more, with a much simpler regexp, but it fails, with the "`address`" line as the last `}` will be removed with your `RS`, and it will print a final `}`...

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="}\n" }
{
  sub("@[^,]\+,","")
  print $0
}' INPUTFILE
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but the wait still, for example, a regular expression. See my edit, and proposed solutions.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Your first proposed solution suits me.

Answer (score 2):

One way without using regular expressions. Set *Field Separator* to a newline and now each key of a register will be a field. With that, traverse each field and print those that don't begin with `@`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { 
        RS="}\n"; 
        FS=OFS="\n"; 
    } 
    { 
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
            if ( substr($i, 1, 1) != "@" ) { 
                printf "%s%s", $i, (i == NF) ? RS : OFS; 
            } 
        } 
    }
' file
```

Output:

```
author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
title =    {Semantic Knowledge Engineering. A Rule-Based Approach},
publisher =    {Wydawnictwa AGH},
year =     2011,
address =  {Krak\'ow}

Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
Journal =  {Journal of Universal Computer Science},
Number =   7,
Pages =    {1006-1023},
Title =    {Collective Knowledge Engineering with Semantic Wikis},
Volume =   16,
Year =     2010
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Your example leaves the "}" at the end of the last line. See my edit, and proposed solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `GNU sed` to do this:

```
sed '/^@/,/^}$/ { //d }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
  author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
  title =    {Semantic Knowledge Engineering. A Rule-Based Approach},
  publisher =    {Wydawnictwa AGH},
  year =     2011,
  address =  {Krak\'ow}

  Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
  Journal =  {Journal of Universal Computer Science},
  Number =   7,
  Pages =    {1006-1023},
  Title =    {Collective Knowledge Engineering with Semantic Wikis},
  Volume =   16,
  Year =     2010
```

Note that you can use the `-i` flag to make the changes in-place (i.e. overwrite the files contents) and you can use the `-s` flag to make the changes to multiple files. For example:

```
sed -s -i '/^@/,/^}$/ { //d }' *.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but the wait still, for example, a regular expression. See my edit, and proposed solutions.

Comment: @Tedee12345: Not being able to change `awk`'s record separator creates more problems than it solves. And coding around these problems is never a good idea. You should consider posting why you think keeping `RS="}\n"` is a good idea. If so, please include more sample data. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if($0!~/@/&&$0!~/^}/)print}' temp
```

tested below:

```
> awk '{if($0!~/@/&&$0!~/^}/)print}' temp
  author =       {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
  title =        {Semantic Knowledge Engineering. A Rule-Based Approach},
  publisher =    {Wydawnictwa AGH},
  year =         2011,
  address =      {Krak\'ow}

  Author =       {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
  Journal =      {Journal of Universal Computer Science},
  Number =       7,
  Pages =        {1006-1023},
  Title =        {Collective Knowledge Engineering with Semantic Wikis},
  Volume =       16,
  Year =         2010
>
```

Comment: This answer is almost identical to Zolts answer 20 hours ago. You should consider up-voting it, like I have.

Comment: Thank you for your example of a solution.